# Multiple filters not work in HBase 1.2.6

Tags: java, hbase

My HBase schema looks like as following:

```
{
    "<trace-id>": {
        "span-timestamp": {
            "ts:span:<timestamp>": ""
        },
        "span-name": {
            "ts:span:<name>": ""
        },
        "span-duration": {
            "ts:span:<duration>": ""
        },
        "span-blob": {
            "ts:span:<span-id>": "<span>"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "ts:endpoint:<service-name>": ""
        },
        "annotation": {
            "ts:annotation:<value>": ""
        },
        "binary-annotation": {
            "ts:binary-annotation:<key>": "<value>",
        },
    }
}
```

In my circumstance, I need query specific qualifiers, so I constructed following filters:

```
final FilterList filters = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
final Charset cs = HOperation.CHARSET;
filters.addFilter(Filters.qualifier(Schema.SCHEMA_TRACES_ENDPOINT, CompareOp.EQUAL, request.serviceName));
filters.addFilter(Filters.qualifier(Schema.SCHEMA_TRACES_SPAN_NAME, CompareOp.EQUAL, request.spanName));
filters.addFilter(Filters.qualifier(Schema.SCHEMA_TRACES_SPAN_TIMESTAMP,
request.endTs * 1000 - request.lookback * 1000, request.endTs * 1000));
filters.addFilter(new PageFilter(request.limit));
scan.setFilter(filters);
scan.setLoadColumnFamiliesOnDemand(true);
```

As you can see, I've bound column family filter with qualifier filter, which means the row will be returned only if both of family filter and qualifier filter evaluate to true.

```
static FilterList qualifier(final Schema schema, final CompareOp op, final byte[] value) {
    final FilterList list = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    list.addFilter(new FamilyFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(schema.cf().getBytes(HOperation.CHARSET))));
    list.addFilter(new QualifierFilter(op, new BinaryComparator(value)));
    return list;
}
```

After I've tried the code, I found my find method based on `Table#getScanner(Scan)` could not work properly.

What's more, I found these two filters could not work together:

```
filters.addFilter(Filters.qualifier(Schema.SCHEMA_TRACES_ENDPOINT, CompareOp.EQUAL, request.serviceName));
filters.addFilter(Filters.qualifier(Schema.SCHEMA_TRACES_SPAN_NAME, CompareOp.EQUAL, request.spanName));
```

Typically, when I comment out any one of these two filters it work. Of course, not perfectly work, cause I need it return `limit` rows, however, it's not.

Any ideas would be appreciate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days research about HBase, I finally figured out the real reason why these multiple filters not working properly together.

In HBase, `Filter` is obviously for output not just working as an condition.

For example, if a row (with row key `row`) with 3 columns called as `cf:A`,`cf1:1`,`cf2:2`(column family is obviously `cf`,`cf1`,`cf2`).

---

Situation 1:

Applying a `FamilyFilter` and the family must be `cf`, this will not return any family that not match(only those families with name of `cf` returned for one row), in this scenario, `cf1:1` and `cf2:2` will not be included in return value.

---

Situation 2:

Applying a `QualifierFilter` and the qualifier must be `1`, than only `cf1:1` will be returned.

---

Of course, these situations should be easy to understand.

---

**However**, how about applying these filters together? The result is interesting. If you try to applying following filters:

```
QualifierFilter(=,'binary:1') && QualifierFilter(=,'binary:2')
```

It seems like you want to get rows with both qualifier `1` and `2`exist no matter which family it belongs to. Actually, you won't get `row` caused there is no **column** matching those two filters at same time.

---

After all, this is not best practice for using HBase. In chapter 34(**Table Schema Rules Of Thumb**) of official reference, there are suggestions for building schemas. And this question is not best designed and confused with RDBMS.